# copy constructor called twice

Tags: c++

Compiler gcc 4.5.3 (cygwin)

I'm trying to determine under what conditions the copy constructor is called for an argument, and I would like to discover a way to pass an argument that does not require the copy constructor to be called. I constructed the following test code to explore this issue.

In the following code the copy constructor is called twice for fnc1(). Any reason why it should be called more than once?

Is there any way to not have the copy constructor called?

```c
# include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class able {
public:
   long x;
   able(): x(1) {}
   able(const able&) {cout << " const "; }
   ~able() { cout << " ~able" << endl; }
};

able fnc1(able x)         { cout << "fnc1(able x)"         ; return x; }
able fnc2(able& x)        { cout << "fnc2(able& x)"        ; return x; }
able fnc3(const able&  x) { cout << "fnc3(const able&  x)" ; return x; }
able fnc4(able const & x) { cout << "fnc4(able const & x)" ; return x; }
able fnc5(able* x)        { cout << "fnc4(able* x)"        ; return *x; }

int main(int argc, char** argv) {

   able* x = new able();
   fnc1(*x);
   fnc2(*x);
   fnc3(*x);
   fnc4(*x);
   fnc5(x);
   cout << "test fini" << endl;
   return 0;
}

output
 const fnc1(able x) const  ~able
  |                 |      |
  |                 |      o first destrucor
  |                 |      
  |                 o second call
  o first call
 ~able
 |
 o second destructor
fnc2(able& x) const  ~able
fnc3(const able&  x) const  ~able
fnc4(able const & x) const  ~able
fnc4(able* x) const  ~able
test fini
```

Comment: Not really relevant to your question itself, but why would you create your object on the heap (and not clean it up at all)? something wrong with `able x;`?

Answer (score 6):

You are passing the `able` object into the function by value and then returning it by value. Each of these involves a copy and will use your copy constructor. First it is copied into the function with `fnc1(*x);`. Then that copy is copied out of the function with `return x;`.

As for the order of your output, what you're witnessing is:

1. `const`

   Object is copied - this is the object being passed into the function as an argument.
2. `fnc1(able x)`

   Execution of `fnc1`.
3. `const`

   Object is copied again - this is the object being returned from the function.
4. `~able`

   Destructor is called - this is the copy created in passing the argument being destroyed because you've reached the end of the functions scope.
5. `~able`

   Destructor is called - this is the temporary object that was returned from the function being destroyed when the line `fnc1(*x);` completes.

The second copy, caused by `return x;`, may be elided by the compiler (even if it has some side effects):

> in a return statement in a function with a class return type, when the expression is the name of a non-volatile automatic object (other than a function or catch-clause parameter) with the same cv-unqualified type as the function return type, the copy/move operation can be omitted by constructing the automatic object directly into the function's return value

Comment: @LihO It might be elided anyway, even without the initialisation, right? (See quote I added to my answer)

Comment: Ah yeah. I forgot about *copy elision*, which applies right in the situation that I pointed out in first comment.

Comment: Without doubt, "awesome". Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

In this function:

```
able fnc1(able x) { ... }
```

You are:

1. Taking the input argument *by value*. This means a *copy* of it will be created to initialize `x`. This is the reason for the **first** invocation of the copy constructor.
2. Returning an object of type `able` *by value*: this means a temporary will be constructed which is a copy of the object you are returning, although this last call to the copy constructor (and then to the destructor, of course) may be elided by the compiler under the [**(Named) Return Value Optimization**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Return_value_optimization), or (N)RVO. This is the reason for the **second** invocation of the copy constructor.

Hence, the **two** calls to the copy constructor that you are seeing.

Also notice, that your program **leaks memory**. You are allocating an object with `new`, and you are never deallocating it through a corresponding call to `delete`.

Comment: Ditto ("awesome"). Any way to elide the copy constructor from being called for the input argument?

Comment: @ArthurSchwarez: That's a compiler's decision that you cannot influence, but it is often done when heavy optimization levels are used. On GCC, you can use the -O3 command-line option

Comment: This is a test program of not possible use in 'real' code. True it leaks like a sieve, but I'm not testing for sieves this week (this is a JOKE, not to be taken seriously and is not a slur).

Comment: @ArthurSchwarez It can be done, but it's not copy elision as the standard defines it. It could only be done on the argument passed if the copy had no side effects, under the as-if rule (the compiler can do whatever the hell it likes as long as your program behaves the same). Copy elision is when the standard says "you can remove this copy construction *even if* it has some side effects". The passing of an argument is not one of the cases in which it can happen.

Comment: @ArthurSchwarez: No worries, I just wanted to point it out :-)

Answer (score 0):

This function:

```
able fnc1(able x) { ... }
```

will require that a copy is made of the object - That's part of the contract when you use a class without reference. That allows fnc1() to "mess" with the object and the original object passed in to remain the same - which is sometimes exactly what you want.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want the responsibility of the 'able' object shifted to the caller. In that case, you'd have a prototype like `void fn1(able &x)`, and it's up to the caller to create a private copy of the  `x` object if it doesn't want its preciousss to be messed up.

One copy for the parameter, one copy for the return value, as others said.

As long as you return an *new object* from your function, you need a constructor to build that object. If you don't want a new object at that point, then your function should return a pointer or a reference to that other object. However,

1. you *must not* return a reference on something you constructed locally on this stack frame (that is, a local variable or a function argument)
2. imvho, if you're just updating the content referenced by the caller, then it make no sense to return a reference to that object, and it would be equally simple to have a "setter-like" API where you have `void` as return type.

The only reason I can see for not following #2 would be that you want to chain functions, i.e. you value `obj->fn1()->fn2()->fn3()` over other programming patterns. In that case, I'd suggest that you receive and return *pointers* to `able` objects, and live with the fact that `fnx()` use `obj->m` rather than `obj.m` to access members.

Comment: The question I have is "is it possible to pass an argument without the copy constructor being called"? I had expected that fnc[2-4]() would have elided the copy constructor, at least fnc[3-4]() but this proves not to be the case.