# Reduce Copy Constructor Calls

Tags: c++, copy-constructor, rvo

The following code is a minimal example from a project that I'm working on.  The main question is that I want to cut down the number of calls to the copy constructor, but it is not clear to me the right way to do this.

```
#include<iostream>

class MyClass
{
public:
    MyClass() {std::cout << "Default Constructor\n";}
    MyClass(const MyClass &input) {std::cout << "Copy Constructor\n";}
    MyClass & operator=(const MyClass &input) 
         {std::cout << "Assignment\n"; return *this;}
    MyClass & operator+=(const MyClass &input) {return *this;}
    friend MyClass operator+(MyClass lhs,const MyClass &);
};

MyClass operator+(MyClass lhs,const MyClass &rhs) 
    {lhs+=rhs;return lhs;}

int main()
{
    MyClass a,b,c;
    c=a+b;
    return 0;
}
```

When I run the code, the output is:

```
Default Constructor
Default Constructor
Default Constructor
Copy Constructor
Copy Constructor
Assignment
```

- The three default constructors are called in the construction of a, b, and c.
- The two copy constructors are called for the first argument in operator+ and the return for operator+.
- The assignment assigns the result from assigning a+b to c.

**Main Question:** In my application, the copy constructor is expensive (it involves memory allocation).  Assignment, on the other hand, is relatively cheap.  What is the proper way to have fewer calls to the copy constructor?

I've considered a few solutions, but none make me happy:

- As I understand, from reading, the operator+ should not have a reference for the first argument since this helps with chaining temporaries.  Therefore, this copy constructor seems unavoidable.
- The following code is significantly faster (due to no copy constructor calls): `c = a; c += b;`  I could write my code using this format, but this requires more a more delicate approach.  I would prefer the compiler to be smarter than for me to make these tweaks myself.
- I could implement a function `add(MyClass &,const MyClass &,const MyClass &);` but this loses the ease of using the addition operator (and requires a lot of (mindless) coding due to the number of different data types that I'm using).
- I've looked at the questions, but I don't see any suggestions that might improve performance in this case:

[Copy constructor called twice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32410254/why-copy-constructor-called-twice), [Copy constructor called twice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15057674/copy-constructor-called-twice), and [Conditions for copy elision](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6383639/conditions-for-copy-elision)

Responses to comments:

- The private data includes MPFR's and MPFI's and the constructor includes initialization of this data.  Perhaps a different implementation of the constructors would be appropriate, but I'm not sure.
- I considered a move constructor, but there are times when I want a copy copy assignment as well.  From [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/move_constructor) it appears that these cannot coexist (or at least there was an error when I tried it at first).  It appears that this should be the best option.

Comment: Why not pass (constant) references to the `operator+` function?

Comment: "As I understand, from reading, the operator+ should not have a reference for the first argument" - where did you read that?

Comment: And according to [this canonical implementation reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operators#Canonical_implementations) the [binary operators](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operators#Binary_arithmetic_operators) *should* be implementd using each other. Like using `operator+=` to implement `operator+`. In *that* case you *should* pass the first argument by value.

Comment: @NeilButterworth At [Cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operators), the example on operator+ states that "passing lhs by value helps optimize chained a+b+c"

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude In my implementation, I am using operator+= to implement operator+ (I just didn't include it to keep the code concise - perhaps I should add it).

Comment: Probably should add it, since as given there is no reason to optimize for chained a+b+c using pass-by-value of the first parameter.

Comment: @Eljay Edited to include operator+=

Comment: Constructor elision will depend on what the contents of the class are. The constructor calls aren't expensive if you don't use iostreams in them. You should add into your question a complete description of what the data members of the class are (ideally: code, not prose - that's always preferable!). Otherwise I'd say "your class does nothing - remove the redundant debug output and you won't have any calls" - i.e. a made-up problem. To make the problem real requires more detail.

Comment: @KubaOber In my case, the private data consists of MPFR/MPFI's.  I've run tests to see that there is a *significant* cost to the constructors.  I can add more of the meat to the question, but I was trying to focus on a minimal example.

Comment: Also note that if you do expensive things in the constructors/copy-constructors, then your design (or your implementation of it) *might* be flawed. I recommend you strive for [the rule of zero](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three#Rule_of_zero) and then you don't have to worry about such things.

Comment: How expensive is moving?  You could implement/use move operators to save on copies.

Comment: There is enough information only to suggest you to define a move constructor and you _literally_ will not have copy constructor calls.

Comment: I concur with that assessment. Both move-ctor and move-assignment could be utilized by this. [See it live](https://ideone.com/vRZSR0). Frankly, I'd implement them *both* if your design allows for it (it likely does).

Comment: @NikitaKniazev I had tried to implement a move constructor, and got errors from my compiler.  I will try again.

Comment: @MichaelBurr Well, maybe there's significant cost to the constructors of the types of the members that you're using, and that's where you should also focus. Maybe those types aren't the most efficient. Again, as it stands, you're focusing on a tiny sliver of a problem that may have a much simpler solution.

Comment: To optimize away the copy construction turn on compiler optimizations. Use move semantics to reduce further.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In other to minimize copy constructor calls, I recommend you define the move constructor and that you perfect-forward your operator arguments. Move constructor:

```
MyClass(MyClass &&input) {std::cout << "Move Constructor\n";}
```

Perfect-forwarding operator:

```
template<typename T>
    friend MyClass operator+(T &&lhs,T &&rhs) {return std::forward<T>(lhs);}
```

With the right calls, your operator will involve a move constructor instead of a copy constructor. For instance, if you add objects that come out of a function and store the result immediately (e.g. `MyClass c=a+b;` instead of `MyClass c;c=a+b;`), thanks to [RVO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copy_elision#Return_value_optimization) you can save the copy constructor.

Let's say you have a function that returns a `MyClass` instance:

```
MyClass something() {return MyClass();}
```

If you add the function return values and store them immediately, e.g.:

```
MyClass c=something()+something();
```

Then no copy constructor will be ever involved.

I have put a series of examples [here](https://ideone.com/nEjaF0) where I used the `const MyClass&` parameter with `operator+` and perfect-forwarding parameters with `operator-`. You can see that it makes a difference in the last example but not in all the other ones. That's why I said "with the right calls". If you have to manipulate objects that can be forwarded like that, it might be worth a shot.

Answer (score 1):

You're passing `lhs` by copy. This is why you have additional copy constructor call. Modify your `operator+`:

`MyClass operator+(const MyClass &lhs, const MyClass &rhs)`

Comment: If I do this, then I'll need to create a new MyClass object inside operator+ to store the sum as I don't want to change lhs and rhs.  This doesn't reduce the number of constructor calls.